# UIStoryboard UIView controller

Tags: ios, xcode

In published my app with a UIViewController connected to the main .h file in Storyboard. The controller can not be reached in any way (it is not connected with a segue to any other view controller. My doubt is: Does this controller take up memory? The codes don't run if the controller is not opened, or am I wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your program is loaded, an instance of `UIStoryboard` is created, which loads the storyboard file (a flat XML) and parses it. Therefore there *is* some memory that is associated with your ViewController. However, until the ViewController is not loaded, it is neither allocated nor instantiated.

That said, you *can* load `UIViewController` from the storyboard *without* connecting it with a segue. This is done using the Identifier of the `UIViewController` with the Method `-instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` of your `UIStoryboard`.

If this does not happen in your code, the only memory the definition of the `UIViewController` causes is associated with the instance of your `UIStoryboard`.